# The default selecting path in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

What is the default path ( selecting file) of browse control in MFC?

In my application if I click on browse button it is opening C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319. Can you people tell me the behaviour of browse button in mFC ?

Comment: What do you mean by "browse control"? `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl`?

Comment: i mean by "browse contro Cfilecontrol

Comment: Can you give the exact class name? There does not seem to be any CFileControl or CFileCtrl.

Comment: Please show us your code or an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `CFileDialog` for browse option use like this

```
CString strFilePath;  // CString variable to save file path
CFileDialog m_dlg1(TRUE,NULL,L"c:\\Program Files\\",OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, NULL, NULL);

if(m_dlg1.DoModal() == IDOK)
    strFilePath = m_dlg1.GetPathName();
```

It will open `c:\\Program Files` directory